# Apple Watch coreLocation error *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation]

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, core-location

I tried to get user current location on Apple Watch with coreLocation. Whenever I run `-[CLLocationManager requestLocation]`, the app quits and give the following error.

```
2016-02-07 16:38:39.392 Placescope Apple Watch Extension[6255:1471552]     *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework_Sim/CoreLocation-1861.3.25.31/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:816
2016-02-07 16:38:39.395 Placescope Apple Watch Extension[6255:1471552] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00bb9fc4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00671df4 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00bb9e5a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x0029a008 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   CoreLocation                        0x0013a4f9 CLClientGetCapabilities + 12683
    5   Placescope Apple Watch Extension    0x0002edbf -[Recommendations awakeWithContext:] + 447
    6   WatchKit                            0x000c2930 _WKInterfaceControllerCreateClass + 482
    7   WatchKit                            0x000af002 __48-[SPRemoteInterface handlePlist:fromIdentifier:]_block_invoke_2 + 470
    8   WatchKit                            0x000aebb9 __48-[SPRemoteInterface handlePlist:fromIdentifier:]_block_invoke + 1245
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0415a71b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x041783fd _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x04160fbe _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 689
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00b066fe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00ac49a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2356
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00ac3db6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00ac3bcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    16  Foundation                          0x0022dac1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
    17  Foundation                          0x002d499d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82
    18  libxpc.dylib                        0x0448206f _xpc_objc_main + 486
    19  libxpc.dylib                        0x04484dce xpc_main + 215
    20  Foundation                          0x003fe3cd service_connection_handler + 0
    21  PlugInKit                           0x035f1232 -[PKService run] + 582
    22  WatchKit                            0x000d1549 main + 146
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0419dad5 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my code:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager requestLocation];
```

If you have a better way to get user's location please let me know as well.

Comment: There should be more to the error message that tells you what the problem is

Comment: That error message doesn't really make sense, are you doing something in the debugger to cause that? Maybe logging something from a breakpoint?

Comment: It wouldn't solve the problem but you should be able to see the real error message now

Comment: The error message is the same unfortunately. It's still showing the following:2016-02-07 16:26:09.421 Placescope Apple Watch Extension[5734:1409833] *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework_Sim/CoreLo‌​cation-1861.3.25.31/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:816

Comment: There will always be an additonal message as well as a stack trace after you get an exception like that. You might have to turn off/step past any exception breakpoints you have to get it to print out

Comment: You are absolutely right! I have gotten rid of every exception breakpoints. I will update the question!

Comment: The important part of the error message is the  'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'.  You have to implement `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` and `locationManager:didFailWithError:` in your delegate in order to use `requestLocation`

Comment: that totally solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dan, You should post your comment as an answer since the problem is solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the error message, `'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'` I have to implement `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` and `locationManager:didFailWithError:` in my delegate in order to use requestLocation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether we can use Location Manager in apple watch.I think we need to go back to parent app to get the CLLocation using watch connectivity.

Comment: Actually, I can. Using the advice from Dan in the comments above, I implemented delegate methods and everything works fine. In another word, problem solved!